# error when precompile assets with turbo-sprockets-rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have installed [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem for precompile assets with capistrano.

I have added `load 'deploy/assets'` to my `Capfile` and the deploy finish fine.

However when I try load my app on remote server I can see inside my `production.log` file the next errors:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap-modalmanager.js isn't precompiled):
    7:     <%= display_meta_tags :site => "9cvs" %>
    8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    9:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-modalmanager" %>
    11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.back_to_top" %>
    12:     <%= javascript_include_tag "swfobject" %>
    13:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

`bootstrap-modalmanager.js` is found inside `vendor/javascripts/` folder. Also I have css files inside `vendor/stylesheets/` and swf files inside `vendor/flash/` folder.

**How can I precompile this assets correctly?**

Comment: Why not include all of those in your application.js? Are you only loading them on certain pages?

Comment: How can I all these files in application.js? Thank you. These files are found in vendor folder. Thank you

Comment: in your application.js you should be able to add `//= require jquery.back_to_top` and `//= require bootstrap-modalmanager` and `//= require swfobject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in your `production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += ['bootstrap-modalmanager.js', 'jquery.back_to_top.js', 'swfObject.js']
```